# Periodic snapshot fact table - Possibly missing some captures

Tags: mysql, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, fact-table

I am tracking employee changes daily in a DimPerson dimension table, and filling up my fact table each end-of-month and counting Hires, Exits, and Headcount.
For this example, let's say I will be populating the fact table end-of-month April 30th. Now here's the problem I am facing:
I have an employee record on April 17th that's a "Hire" action, so at that point in time my DimPerson table reads like this:

```
+-------+-----------+----------+--------+--------------------+-------+
| EmpNo | Firstname | LastName | Action | EffectiveStartDate | isCur |
+-------+-----------+----------+--------+--------------------+-------+
| 4590  | John      | Smith    | Hire   | 4/17/2017          | Y     |
+-------+-----------+----------+--------+--------------------+-------+
```

Now 2 days later, I see the same employee but with an action "Manager Change", so now my DimPerson table becomes this:

```
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------+
| EmpNo | Firstname | LastName |     Action      | EffectiveStartDate | isCur |
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------+
| 4590  | John      | Smith    | Hire            | 4/17/2017          | N     |
| 4590  | John      | Smith    | Manager Change  | 4/19/2017          | Y     |
+-------+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------+
```

So at Month end, when I select all "Current" employees, I will miss the Hire capture for this person since his most recent record is just a manager change and the actual hiring happened "in-month". 
Is this normal that you can miss certain changes when doing a periodic snapshot? What you recommend I do to capture the Hire action in this case?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you need to fill up your fact table differently- you need a reliable source of numbers of hires, exits and headcount. You could pick those events up directly from the source system if available, or pick them up from your dimension table (if it was guaranteed to contain all the history, and not just end-of-day changes).

The source system would be the best solution, but if the dimension table overall shows the history you need, then rather than selecting the isCur people and seeing their most recent action, you need to get all the dimension table records for the period you are snapshotting, and count the actions of each type.

However I would not recommend you use the dimension table at all to capture transactional history. SCDs on a dimension should be used to track changes to the dimension attributes themselves, not to track the history of actions on the person. Ideally, you would create a transactional fact table to record these actions. That way, you have a transactional fact that records all actions, and you can use that fact table to populate your periodic snapshot at the end of each month, and your dimension table doesn't need to worry about it. Think of your dimension table as a record of the person, not of the actions on the person.

Comment: When you say the source system, do you mean to say that I should omit the start schema all together and just base my calculations on the data source?
Also for the transactional fact table, would that be one row per employee per day?

Comment: I meant instead that rather than trying to use the dimension to find the actions on your people when building your periodic snapshot, you could go back to the place your dimension got them from in the first place. So yes, basing your calculations on the data source. But the transactional fact would be nice if you need to analyse these actions in their own right. The transactional fact would be one row per action, so you'd only get actions for an employee on a day if one existed, and you'd potentially get multiple actions for an employee on a day if such things were possible.

Comment: I was mainly basing my dimensional model on Kimball's Human Resources Headcount example. There he would maintain a Person dimension with SCD type 2, and a periodic snapshot fact table of hire / exit counts.
So at each month-end, ideally you would select the current record for each employee and you could count the number of hires and exits for that month-end.

Comment: Also, worth mentioning, I am fairly new to data warehousing so I'm a bit slow on visualising your suggestion. My data source will be a flat file of all employee history since the founding of the company. Each day new rows will be added to it, so we can think of it like a transaction. Each update will denote either a new employee hire, an employee exit, or a change in the current employee status (Manager change, Location change etc...). I also forgot to mention that I have an `EmployeeActivityDim` table. Would that help?

Comment: No worries, happy to help. What is in your EmployeeActivityDim table that is different to you DimEmployee table? What you're after is a DimEmployee table that describes the Employee (name, etc) and a FactEmployeeActivity table with one row per activity. Your fact models the event of an activity. This'd hve your EmployeeKey (from the DimEmployee table) and an EmployeeActivityTypeKey which would be a key into a table called DimEmployeeActivityType which would be one row per type of activity (hire, etc). It'd also have DateKey into your DimDate which would describe the date the activity occurred.

Comment: So my `EmployeeActivityDim` has 3 fields `Action, ActionType and Date`  where `ActionType` can be `Hire` or `Termination` depending on the `Action` being taken (`ActonType` will be NULL if the Action is something like "Manager Change" or "Location Change").
My `EmployeeDim` table, as you said, just describes the employee (empno, first/last name, start date etc...).
So going back to my previous example (the one in my question), I would log on 17th of April a Hire activity, then on the 19th a Manager Change activity in that fact table?

Comment: Assuming your employeeactivitydim also includes employee (which surely it must), it sounds like employeeactivitydim should be a fact, not a dim..And the action and action type from that table should be in an 'activity' dimension which just lists the possible activities, (not the date or employee). Your employeedim would not need a startdate if nothing changes about the columns of an employee when an action happens.

Comment: And yes, your new fact table (EmployeeActivityFact) would have a hire activity on the 17th, and then on the 19th a manager change activity. Finally- its good to avoid the nulls in a dimension for action type- you could have N/A if it doesn't apply.

Comment: Awesome, the EmployeeActivityFact table makes sense. Can you detail a bit more on how I would fill in my Snapshot table at month-end via my Activity Fact table?
Let's say April 30th has arrived, and it's time to populate my Periodic Employee Snapshot table. Do I just select all activities from Employee Activity Fact `Where Date >= CURDATE_START AND Date <= CURDATE_END`?

Comment: Yes something like 'where date >= start_date and date <= end_date sounds good to me. You can do a where on the activity type to get one measure for each activity type as per your question, but you might want to design your periodic snapshot fact to also have an activity dimension and therefore have one periodic snapshot fact row per type of activity you are summarising. You might even be able to do away with your periodic snapshot if you are happy to query over the transaction fact to ask the same questions. Good luck!

Comment: Your month-end snapshot would be a different fact table from the daily fact table.  Don't try to mix grains with the same data.  I'd recommend you add a fact/date relationship for each of the different dates an employee can have.  Hire/Birth/Vested/Termination, etc.  Then you can slice and count your data based on these dimension. (e.g. How many employees are expected to retire next month?)

Comment: I agree they should be different facts, but the question was about missing counts. A transactional fact as a separate fact to the monthly periodic snapshot would solve this.

Answer (score -1):

If your fact is intended to show the organizational change at the month end, I would say it is working as designed.  The employee has a manager at the end of the month, but did not exist at the end of the previous month.  This implies the employee was hired during the month.  With a monthly grain, it should not be expected to show the daily activity.

Our employee dimension contains the hire date as a Type 1 attribute.  We also include hire date in certain fact tables to allow a role playing relationship with the date dimension.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share a high level schema of your employee dim and fact table? I insert a 1 for Hirecount if the current employee record in the dimension table has a hire action, if it's an exit action I count an exit. And for any action other than exit I count 1 for headcount. This is all done at month end.

Comment: Sorry, I can't share the schema as our HR group is very strict and there is no business need to disclose it.

Comment: I'll try to implement via monthly grain and see if there is a business need to reduce it to a daily grain